# Where does Magento store placeholder images?

Tags: image, configuration

As per the title, I'm trying to establish which directory Magento stores the placeholder images which you set up in:

`System` → `Configuration` → `Catalogue` → `Product Image Placeholders`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, the default image, small image & thumbnail image are stored in:

- `media/catalog/product/placeholder/default/image.jpg`,
- `media/catalog/product/placeholder/default/small_image.jpg`, and
- `media/catalog/product/placeholder/default/thumbnail.jpg`

respectively.

Comment: In my project, there is no directory names 'placeholder' under media/catalog/product.
I am using magento v1.9.2.2.
Any idea?